# Groovy to capture response headers in Structure other than Map

Tags: web-services, grails, groovy, webclient, soapui

I am trying to capture web service response via Groovy client, I have to check for duplicate header keys in response. I am capturing response headers using messageExchage.responseHeaders(), but since it returns map, It gives me each key only once, even though it is present twice in a response. is there a way to get this in Array or some other data structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rawResponseAsString = new String( messageExchange.getRawResponseData())
log.info rawResponseAsString
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you accessing the web service?  If you use the [groovy HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/HTTP+Builder), you can iterate through the headers, duplicates keys included:

```
new HTTPBuilder('http://webservice/').with {
    request(Method.GET) {
        uri.path = '/'
        response.success = { resp ->
            assert resp.status == 200
            resp.headers.each {
                println "${it.name}: ${it.value}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am accessing web service using soapUI tool, and then adding this groovy script as a part of assertion. So the only way to access header is via messageExchange object.